# qt creator смена кодировки

Tags: c++, qt, кодировка, creator

Ребят помогите,проблемы в том что char не преобразовывается в wchar, хотя в visual studio этот же код робит, а в qt creator нет, я предполагаю что нужно сменить кодировку с unicode на многобайтовую, подскажите как это сделать или другие пути решения этой проблемы, спасибо!

Comment: При преобразовании из char в wchar обычно как раз необходимо делать обратное - преобразовывать из многобайтовой в кодировку с фиксированным размером символа. И без привлечения внешних библиотек это может работать только для ASCII символов.

Comment: Qt Creator - всего лишь IDE, как и  Visual Studio. Ты используешь Mingw32 или MSVC компилятор?

Comment: MSVC использую в qt